# InActive Redshift Tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Time-to-Time redshift users create persistent temporary tables for their computational purpose. which is good, but such short-term tables gets piled up over a period time and don't convey any meaning to our warehouse.
    Is there any redshift SQL or redshift way of figuring out when the table was last accessed (select, insert, delete, load, unload). based on the timing we can give warning to the users and drop it.

Answer (score 1):

The [STL_QUERY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) and [SQL_QUERYTEXT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERYTEXT.html) tables contain information about queries that have been run on Amazon Redshift.

```
select query, substring(text,1,60)
from stl_querytext
where pid = pg_backend_pid()
order by query desc;

 query |                         substring
-------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 28262 | select query, substring(text,1,80) from stl_querytext where 
 28252 | select query, substring(path,0,80) as path from stl_unload_l
 28248 | copy category from 's3://dw-tickit/manifest/category/1030_ma
 28247 | Count rows in target table
 28245 | unload ('select * from category') to 's3://dw-tickit/manifes
 28240 | select query, substring(text,1,40) from stl_querytext where 
(6 rows)
```

You could analyze these queries to **determine which tables have been recently queried**, and then compare them against [SVV_TABLEINFO](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) to determine what tables have **not** been used recently.

You should also encourage users to use `CREATE TEMP TABLE`, which creates a table that is **automatically dropped at the end of the sessio**n. You might be able to use permissions to force certain groups of users to only create TEMP tables, or tables in their own schema.

Comment: looks like that is the way. we have different reporting sources like looker , wagon etc. each of them issues command differently with different syntax and its hard to parse the SQL. but i will pursue your path to solve our problem and come with permission level fix. thanks